# Verification of basic vector space properties, and perspective on vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

This is from pages 111--112 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher.

**Definition and notation:**

> [image]

**Exercise:**

It is suggested on page 112 that I prove that $(-\lambda)v = \lambda(-v) = -(\lambda v) =: - \lambda v$ and that $\lambda v = 0 \Rightarrow (\lambda = 0 \text{ or } v = 0)$. (Here the first and last zeros are elements of $V$, while the second zero is an element of $K$.)

I am given that $0v = 0$.

**My attempt:**

First we try to prove that $(-\lambda)v = -(\lambda v)$.

\begin{align*}
\lambda v + (-\lambda) v &= \big( \lambda + (-\lambda) \big) v\\
&= 0v\\
&= 0\\
\Rightarrow (-\lambda)v &= -(\lambda v).
\end{align*}

Next we show that $(-1)v = -v$.

\begin{align*}
v + (-1)v &= 1v + (-1)v\\
&= \big(1 + (-1) \big)v\\
&= 0v\\
&= 0\\
\Rightarrow (-1)v &= -v.
\end{align*}

Now we try to equate $(-\lambda)v = \lambda(-v)$.

\begin{align*}
(-\lambda)v &= \big( (-1)\lambda)v\\
&= \big( \lambda (-1) \big) v\\
&= \lambda \big( (-1)v \big)\\
&= \lambda (-v).
\end{align*}

That concludes the first part. For the second part, assume that $\lambda v = 0$ and yet $\lambda \neq 0$ and $v \neq 0$ (their respective zero elements).

\begin{align*}
\lambda v &= 0\\
\Rightarrow \lambda v + \lambda v &= 0\\
\Rightarrow \lambda (v + v) &= 0.
\end{align*}

Thus $\lambda v = \lambda (v + v)$, and after multiplying both sides by $\lambda^{-1}$, we see that $v = v + v$, which implies that $v = 0$, a contradiction.

**Questions:**

Are my proofs correct?

I am trying to develop a more "mature" perspective on vector spaces. I have some prior experience with linear algebra, but when I think "vector space", I tend to think about $\mathbb R^n$. I don't think this is helpful. Looking at the definition given in the text, it is striking to me how much the definition of a vector space looks like a group action. Therefore I am wondering if it would be better to think of a vector space as a "field action on an abelian group" such that the two structures play nicely with each other. Is this a reasonable conception to hold?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. A vector space over a field $K$ of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $K^n$. So thinking of $\Bbb R^n$ is not so unhelpful, although we have many fields, also finite fields. 2. One natural generalisation of a $K$-vector space is a module over a ring $R$. A module over $\Bbb Z$ is an abelian group, but a module over a field $K$ is just a $K$-vector space.

Comment: Your proof look fine! You didn't need to show that $(-1)v=-v$ as that's a special case of $(-\lambda)v=-(\lambda v)$. Another approach for the second part would be to show $\lambda 0 = 0$ and then multiply the equation $\lambda v = 0$ by $\lambda^{-1}$ when $\lambda \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see where you proved that $0v=0.$
2. It is customary to use $+$ for  the addition in the field $K$ and also for the operation of the group $V.$ And to use $0$ for the additive identity of $K$ and also for the identity of the group $V.$ And to use $-l$ for the additive inverse of $l\in K$ while using $-v$ for the group inverse of $v\in V.$
3. For $v\in V$ we have $v=1\cdot v=(1+0)v=(1\cdot v)+(0\cdot v)=v+(0\cdot v).$ So $(0\cdot v)$ is the identity of the group $V,$ that is $0v=0.$
4. For $l\in K$  we have by 3. that  $0=0v =(l+(-l))v=lv+(-l)v.$ Therefore $(-l)v$ is the inverse of $lv$ in the group $V,$ that is $(-l)v=-(lv).$ So we can write it as $-lv$ without needing to clarify whether the "$-$" applies to $l$ in $K$ or to $lv$ in $V.$
5. If $0\in V$ and $l\in K,$ then  we have $(l0)=l(0+0)=(l0)+(l0)$ so the 2nd "$l0$" in the expression "$(l0)+(l0)$" is the identity of $V$, that is $l0=0.$
6. If $0\ne v\in V$ and $0\ne l\in K$ then since $K$ is a field we have, by replacing $l$ with $l^{-1} $ in 5., that $0=lv\implies 0=l^{-1}0=l^{-1}(lv)=(l^{-1}l)v=(1)v=v\ne 0,$ a paradox. Therefore, for any $v\in V$ and any $l\in K$ we have, by this and by 3. and 5. that $lv=0 \iff (l=0\lor v=0).$
7. A vector-space can certainly be regarded as a field action on an Abelian group, in which the type of action is subject to the constraints of the axioms for a vector space. Note that we can have $V=\{0\}.$ This is called the trivial, or $0$-dimensional vector space. Note that if $K'$ is a sub-field of a field $K$ then $K$ can be considered to be a vector space over $K'.$ E.g. $\Bbb R$ is a vector space over the field $\Bbb Q.$
8. It is also often convenient to define $vl=lv$  for $l\in K$ and $v\in V.$